# Why does botulinum toxin cause only NMJ symptoms?

Tags: toxicology, peripheral-nervous-system, bacterial-toxins, infectious-diseases

Botulinum toxin acts by preventing release of ACh by cleaving SNARE proteins. But if it is acting on snare proteins shouldn't all vesicle releases be effected? Why is it limited only to the acetylcholine vesicles in the motor neuron bat the end plate? Why not some other neurotransmitter at some other place like GABA in the brain?